# Java game board array not updating

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array

i'm currently trying to make a clone of the game reversi (for those not familiar, here's an example: http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/reversi.html). The issue im having at the moment is to do with my attempt to update the game board. I have a 2D Array called board, when the user clicks on a particular cell, the board is meant to update with that player. However it doesn't. Here's the code i have thus far:

```
    /* Main.java
 *
 * this is a simple program that will implement the game of reversi, it will only deal with the game itself and a
 * simple scoreboard.
 */

/** includes **/
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/** classes **/

public class Reverse extends JFrame {

    /** constructors **/
    public Reverse() {
        setSize(648, 670);
        setTitle("Reversi");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Initialize Widget
        widget = new ReversiWidget();
        //Initialize Content Pane
        getContentPane().add(widget);
    }

    /** public functions **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reverse w = new Reverse();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

    /** private fields **/
    ReversiWidget widget;   // where the game is being played
}

class ReversiWidget extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int column = 8;
    int row = 8;


    /** constructors **/
    public ReversiWidget() {
        black = this.black;
        cyan = this.cyan;
        white = this.white;

        //Initialize game state
        initialState();

        //add mouse listener
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    /** public functions **/

    // method required by MouseListener. not used
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    // method required by MouseListener. not used
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    // method required by MouseListener. not used
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {

    }

    // will react to mouse press events on the widget
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        //get value of left button clicked
        if(event.getButton() == 3){


        }
    }

    // will react to mouse release events on the widget
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        //determine value for newx and newy
        //get mouse pressed
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        rowSelected = x / sqaure_size;
        colSelected = y / sqaure_size;
        current_player = 1;
        if (rowSelected >= 0 && rowSelected < row && colSelected >= 0 && colSelected < column){
            System.out.println("C Row && C Col: "+rowSelected+"  | "+colSelected);
            System.out.println(oldx+" | "+oldy);
            board[rowSelected][colSelected] = current_player;
            System.out.println("Board Test: "+board[0][0]+", "+board[0][1]+", "+board[0][2]+", "+board[0][3]+", ");
            attemptMove(rowSelected, colSelected, current_player);
        }

    }

    // repaints the widget when an update of any kind is made
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //paint background
        //type cast graphics object

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,640, 640);
        //run draw grid method
        drawGrid(g2d);
        drawPieces(g2d);
    }


    /** private functions **/

    // will take in a position (x,y) a player and will attempt to make a move. if successful then it will place the
    // piece and update the game board.
    private void attemptMove(int x, int y, int player) {

        //repaint();

    }   

    // checks if there is a piece in a given position. returns 0 if empty, -1 if out of bounds, 1 for player 1, and
    // 2 for player 2
    private int checkPiece(int x, int y) {
        return -5;
    }

    // determines if a valid reverse chain can be made from the position (x, y) in the given direction (dx, dy) and a
    // given player
    private boolean determineChain(int x, int y, int dx, int dy, int player) {
        return false;
    }

    // determines if an end game state has been reached. this will happen if there are zero spaces on the board, if one
    // player has lost all of their pieces, or there are no valid moves left for either player
    private boolean determineEndGame() {
        return false;
    }

    // will draw the grid for the game. this assumes a 640 by 640 grid
    private void drawGrid(Graphics2D g2d) {
        //type cast graphics component
        //This is where it gets tricky

                //Here we're going to draw our grid
                int rowCount = width / row;
                int colCount  = height / column;
                int cell = 79;

                //Create Rows
                for(int a=0;a<row;a++){
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.drawLine(0, colCount, 638, rowCount);
                    colCount = colCount + cell;
                    rowCount = rowCount + cell;
                }

                colCount = 79;
                rowCount = 79;
                //Create Columns
                for(int b=0;b<column;b++){
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    //x1,y1  - x2,y2
                    System.out.println("ColCount: "+colCount);
                    g2d.drawLine(colCount, 0, rowCount, 675);
                    colCount = colCount + cell;
                    rowCount = rowCount + cell;

                }

                for (int rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
                 for (int col = 0; col < column; col++) {
                    board[row][column] = 0; // all cells empty
                    System.out.print(board[row][column]);
                 }
                 System.out.println();
              }

    }

    // will draw the pieces that are currently on the board. assumes a widget size of 640 square
    private void drawPieces(Graphics2D g2d) {

        int x = getX();
        int y = getY();
        System.out.println("drawPieces: "+x+" | "+y);
        //Traverse the entire board length to see if a move has been made

        //Black Initial Pieces
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillOval(316, 237, 78,78);
        g2d.fillOval(238, 317, 78,78);

        //White Initial Pieces
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillOval(238, 239, 78,78);
        g2d.fillOval(317, 317, 78,78);
        board[3][3] = 1;
        board[4][3] = 2;
        board[3][4] = 2;
        board[3][3] = 1;
        setBoard(3,3,1);
        setBoard(4,3,1);
        setBoard(3,4,1);
        //setBoard();

        //If move is made draw black piece

                        if(board[rowSelected][colSelected] == 2){
                           g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                           g2d.fillOval(rowSelected, colSelected, 79, 79);
                        }


        //if move is made draw white pieces

                        if(board[rowSelected][colSelected] == 1){
                            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            g2d.fillOval(rowSelected, colSelected, 79, 79);   
                        }





    }

    // will initialise the game board to the starting state
    private void initialState() {
        inPlay = true;
    }

    // given a position (x, y) and a player this will determine if there is a valid move to be made at the given
    // position by checking for the availability of a reverse chain in any direction
    private boolean reverseChainAvailable(int x, int y, int player) {
        return false;
    }   

    // given a position (x, y), direction (dx, dy) and a player this will reverse all opponents pieces in a given
    // direction. NOTE: this assumes that determineChain has been used first. method does not perform checks
    private void reversePieces(int x, int y, int dx, int dy, int player) {

    }

    // called at the end of a valid turn this will swap the current players
    private void swapPlayers() {

    }

    // updates the player scores after a piece has been placed
    private void updatePlayerScores() {

    }

    public void setX(int x){this.oldx = x;}
    public void setY(int y){this.oldy = y;}
    public void setBoard(int x, int y, int player){this.board[x][y] = board[x][y] = player;}

    /** private fields **/
    //initial board state
    public int board[][] = new int[9][9];
    int oldx;
    int oldy;   // denotes where the player clicked when he pressed the mouse button
    int current_player;                 // denotes who the current player is
    int player_1_score, player_2_score; // denotes the score each player has in the game thus far
    boolean inPlay;                     // indicates if the game is being played at the moment
    Color black, cyan, white;           // color objects that represent their named colours
    int sqaure_size = 79;
    int rowSelected = oldx / sqaure_size;
    int colSelected = oldy / sqaure_size;
}
```

The particular issue is to do with this method:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        //determine value for newx and newy
        //get mouse pressed
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        rowSelected = x / sqaure_size;
        colSelected = y / sqaure_size;
        current_player = 1;
        if (rowSelected >= 0 && rowSelected < row && colSelected >= 0 && colSelected < column){
            System.out.println("C Row && C Col: "+rowSelected+"  | "+colSelected);
            System.out.println(oldx+" | "+oldy);
            board[rowSelected][colSelected] = current_player;
            System.out.println("Board Test: "+board[0][0]+", "+board[0][1]+", "+board[0][2]+", "+board[0][3]+", ");
            attemptMove(rowSelected, colSelected, current_player);
        }

    }
```

Edit* please excuse the messiness!

Comment: Unlrelated- Take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and always make sure you are calling `super.paintXxx`, especially when dealing with `JComponent`, otherwise you will end up with unwanted paint artificates.

Comment: Related- You commented out `repaint` in `attemptMove` any reason why?

Comment: Yes, the strange thing is it updates(rePaints) the first cell board[0][0], but no other. I just commented it out for testing. @MadProgrammer will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g2d.fillOval(rowSelected, colSelected, 79, 79)` is going to be a problem, because `rowSelected` & `colSelected` are indices for you board array and don't reflect the view/virtual board offsets, these need to be converted to reflect the graphic grid...

Try using `g2d.fillOval(rowSelected * 79, colSelected * 79, 79, 79)` instead.

Should also avoid using "magic" numbers and either make constants or lookups for these values, so you can change them more easily...

You'll need to uncomment the `repaint` request to make this work...

Oh, you also seem to be modifying the state of the game from within your paint methods, I'd recommend against this, as paints can occur at any time.

Also, make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` before you perform any painting, this will prevent any nasty paint artifacts from appearing, especially when dealing with components that extend from `JComponent`

**Updated**

Painting in Swing is destructive.  That is, each time a paint cycle occurs, you are expected to re-paint the entire state of the component.  Part of the paint process is "clean" the `Graphics` context, this is why it's important to call `super.paintXxx`.

You will need to loop through your boards start and redraw it, for example...

```
for (int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < col; x++) {
        if(board[y][x] == 2){
           g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           g2d.fillOval(y * 79, x * 79, 79, 79);
        } else if(board[y][x] == 1){
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
           g2d.fillOval(y * 79, x * 79, 79, 79);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's filling the cells as it should: http://broconut.com/i/504ef539a9c82.png

Comment: Just another question, what would be the best way to go about storing the player that has made the move? It seems that my game board is still not updating as it should.

Comment: There are few other things I might get slapped about for not mentioning. Generally we are discouraged from extend directly from `JFrame`, generally speaking, your not adding anything to the class.  Instead, simple create an instance and add your `ReversiWidget` to it.  Making `paintComponent` `public` really doesn't make sense, you really don't want any one calling it out of turn, better to leave it as `protected`

Comment: I only see you set the current player to `1` (`current_player = 1;`) in the `mouseReleased` method.  You need to change each time...

Comment: I have that sorted, but what i'm getting is this at the moment: [Image Example](http://broconut.com/i/124e21af23c9c.gif) i can place the circles in the cells as i please, but what i want is to keep them there. Which is what i'm trying to do with the game board.